Why do I get the error "java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'"?
Ps. Stop closing the question and marking it as duplicate pointing at a random solution. IT DOES NOT WORK.
Its been almost a month since i can not find an answer to my issue.
Building the APK will result in success when it comes down to signing into firebase. None of the solutions on forums helped me. I tried EVERYTHING.
The issues happen only when i sign it and upload it to my private testers.
I will get an exception api:10 after trying to login.
The worry is that i always get Failed to get service from broker.  (Ask Gemini) java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
Every time.
here is my build gradle:app with some changes to hide sensitive data.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") // Correct Google Services plugin
    id("com.google.firebase.appdistribution") version "5.0.0"

}

android {
    namespace = "com.XX.XX"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.XX.XX"
        minSdk = 33
        targetSdk = 36
        versionCode = 22
        versionName = "2.4"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            storeFile = file("C:/XX/release.keystore")
            storePassword = "XX"
            keyAlias = "XX"
            keyPassword = "XX"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.play.services.location)
    implementation(libs.appcompat.v160)
    implementation(libs.material.v180)
    implementation(libs.activity.v172)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout.v214)

    // Firebase BOM to manage versions
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.google.firebase.analytics)
    implementation(libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.messaging)
    implementation(libs.google.firebase.firestore)
    implementation(libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.auth)
    implementation(libs.play.services.auth)
    implementation(libs.play.services.location)

    // Testing dependencies
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.junit.v115)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core.v351)
}


my settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } // Include Jitpack if necessary
    }
}

rootProject.name = "XX"
include(":app")

my build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    //alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    id("com.android.application") version "8.7.3" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.appdistribution") version "5.0.0" apply false


}

and my main activity.
package com.XX.XX;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private SignInButton googleSignInButton;
    private TextView authStatusTextView;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 10210;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity Created");

        // Check for Google Play services
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 9000).show();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Play Services not available.");
                finish(); // Or handle the error appropriately
                return;
            }
        }

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        googleSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.googleSignInButton);
        authStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.authStatusTextView);
        googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(v -> signInWithGoogle());

        checkNotificationPermission();
        checkCurrentUser();
    }

    private void checkCurrentUser() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            authStatusTextView.setText("Logged in as: " + currentUser.getDisplayName());
            googleSignInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkFCMToken(currentUser.getUid());
        } else {
            authStatusTextView.setText("Not logged in");
            googleSignInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void checkNotificationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1001);
            } else {
                subscribeToGlobalTopic();
            }
        } else {
            subscribeToGlobalTopic();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1001 && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            subscribeToGlobalTopic();
        } else {
            showToast("Notification permission required for updates.");
        }
    }

    private void signInWithGoogle() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        googleSignInClient.signOut();
        Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign-in failed", e);
            showToast("Authentication Failed." + e);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null))
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        checkCurrentUser();
                    } else {
                        showToast("Authentication Failed.");
                    }
                });
    }

    private void checkFCMToken(String userId) {
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                    if (!task.getResult().contains("fcm_token")) { // Check for *absence* of token
                        getFCMToken();
                    } else {
                        subscribeToGlobalTopic();
                    }
                } else {
                    getFCMToken();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error checking FCM token", task.getException());
            }
        });
    }


    private void subscribeToGlobalTopic() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("global")
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Subscribe to global topic failed", task.getException());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void getFCMToken() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                String token = task.getResult();
                saveTokenToFirestore(token);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM token failed", task.getException());
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveTokenToFirestore(String token) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("fcm_token", token);
            db.collection("users").document(user.getUid())
                    .set(data)
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.w(TAG, "Saving FCM token failed", e));
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}`

My google json is correct and matches the firebase + google oath.
I am getting insane. I would love some help
Tried everything but the error never went away.
